# Gaussian fit to a dataset using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gaussian, data-fitting

I have a dataset

```
d = {{0., 0.},     {0.5, 6.31267}, {0.75, 7.95463}, 
    {1., 8.91956}, {1.5, 9.49294}, {2., 9.01877}, 
    {3., 6.95413}, {5., 3.20838},  {7., 1.31298}}
```

where the first values of each observation correspond to a value of `time-t` and the second to `concentration-c`.

With FindFit, I've been able to obtain the an approximation to a gaussian curve. Nevertheless, I wanted to obtain an approximation with the mean value depending on `t`, with preference to a solution like `mu(t)=ae^(-b1t)- ae^(-b2t)`.

Which comand should i use in order to do that?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` …

Comment: thank you very much, it is perfect!